# Solution to $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + 5 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I asked this question before, I wrote it wrong!

$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} + 5 = 0$$

My friends said the the solution could be :
$$|x-1| = -5$$

 So the solution is nothing!

But I say the solution is:
$$x^2-2x+1 = 25  $$
so $$x = 6\ |\ x = -4$$

My Question here is which solution is right, and why.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you have got $x=6$ and $x=-4$, now put each of them in $\sqrt {x^2-2x+1}+5=0$ to see you are right or wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $\sqrt{x^2-2x+1}$ is always positive, i.e.,
$$\sqrt{x^2-2x+1} = \vert x-1 \vert$$
Hence, no solution exists.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep more studying!

Answer (score 1):

Your friends are correct.
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} + 5 & = 0\\
\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} & = -5\\
\sqrt{(x - 1)^2} & = -5\\
|x - 1| & = -5
\end{align*}
which has no solutions.

By convention, the expression $\sqrt{u}$ means the non-negative square root of $u$.  Therefore, the equation 
$$\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} = -5$$
has no solution.  When you squared both sides of the equation
$$\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} = -5$$
to obtain 
$$x^2 - 2x + 1 = 25$$
you introduced extraneous solutions since the equation $x^2 - 2x + 1 = 25$ has solutions that the equation $\sqrt{x^2 - 2x + 1} + 5 = 0$ does not.

Comment: Thanks, you taught me a thing i didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check the solutions by inserting them.

However, in general by adding positive terms you will never reach the value zero. The same goes by adding a non-negative term to a positive term.

Answer (score 0):

Addition of $2$ positive real numbers gives something positive. Now $5$ is positive and so is the square root of $x^2-2x+1$ i.e $|x-1|$ for all real $x$. Hence their addition must be greater than $5$ and obviously not $0$.

So your friend is right when he says that there is no solution.

Comment: That's disappoint me, and I will have to study more, Thanks.